# match all variants of an enum that contain attached data

Tags: enums, rust, match

I'm just learning and writing a small poker program with the following code:

```
enum Action {
    Fold,
    Check,
    Call(i32),
    Bet(i32),
    Raise(i32),
    Post(i32),
}

// ...

infors[seat] = match action {
    Action::Fold => Status::Out,
    Action::Check => infors[seat],
    Action::Call(x) => infors[seat].incr(x),
    Action::Bet(x) => infors[seat].incr(x),       
    Action::Raise(x) => infors[seat].incr(x),
    Action::Post(x) => infors[seat].incr(x),
};
```

Is there a way to pattern match on all variants with the `i32` field so that the final 4 lines can be combined, since they all do the same thing with x?

Something in the spirit of

```
Action::_(x) => // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
match action {
    Action::Fold => Status::Out,
    Action::Check => infors[seat],
    Action::Call(x) | Action::Bet(x) | Action::Raise(x) | Action::Post(x) => infors[seat].incr(x),
}
```

And if you want to shorten everything, you can `use Action::*`

```
{
    // Only import in this block to avoid name conflicts
    use Action::*;
    match action {
        Fold => Status::Out,
        Check => infors[seat],
        Call(x) | Bet(x) | Raise(x) | Post(x) => infors[seat].incr(x),
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed02b8e7a98c92877b6f6bd6a6b80c43)

Read the Rust Book [Pattern Syntax Chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html) for more information